# Android density independence with same density screens

Tags: android

I have an image that is scaled between mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi. I have put the different images in their corresponding folders, but when I have two devices of the same density, the view is still different. For example, when previewing the layout for the Galaxy Nexus and the Nexus 4, although both are xhdpi the views are still slightly different. Their resolutions are slightly different, with the Nexus 4 being 768 x 1280 and the Galaxy Nexus being 720 x 1280. Can you explain how to achieve density independence with different resolutions but same density?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is nothing to do with density (like you said, both screens have the same density), and everything to do with the fact the screens are just different sizes, specified in dips (device independent pixels).

In Android, you can't design pixel perfect layouts. Instead, you have to design layouts than can stretch to suit different screen sizes, much the same as web development works. That will vary depending on exactly what sort of layout you're trying to achieve.